# HTML5 video - setting video.currentTime breaks the player

Tags: javascript, promise, html5-video

I am trying to interact with a 3rd-party html5 video player in Chrome. I am able to obtain a valid reference to it thusly:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1]
```

...and the `readyState` is 4, so it's all good.

I can successfully (and with expected result) call:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].play();
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].pause();
```

BUT when I call:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].currentTime = 500;
```

...the video freezes and it doesn't advance to the new `currentTime`. The video duration is much longer than 500 seconds, so it should be able to advance to that spot. I have tried other times besides 500, all with same result. If I examine `currentTime`, it is correct as to what I just set. But it doesn't actually go there. Also I can no longer interact with the video. It ignores any calls to `play()` or `pause()` after I try to set `currentTime`.

**Before** I call `currentTime`, when I call `play()` I get this valid promise back, and everything else still works:
[image]

**After** I call `currentTime`, when I call `play()`, I get this broken promise back, and now nothing works on that video object:[image]

If you have a [Hulu](https://www.hulu.com/) account you can easily observe this behavior on any video by simply trying it in the Chrome developer console.

**EDIT**: It was pointed out to me that skipping very much ahead breaks, but skipping a short distance actually works well. Could be related to commercials interspersed.

Comment: what is the value of `video.duration`?

Comment: video.duration = 4864.151

Comment: On what event are you attempting to issue the `.currentTime = 500;` command?

Comment: As indicated in original post: `document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].currentTime = 500;`

Comment: No, `document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1]` is an element, not an event. What I'm asking for is the broader context in which `document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].currentTime = 500;` is executed. Is it on document-ready, on page-load, on the click of a button etc? Also, what state is the player in at the moment the command is issued?

Comment: I reference the video element in chrome developer tools, after video is fully loaded, and the readyState is 4. In my actual software, I get a reference to the video element after page load, and my code confirms that (1) the video object has been obtained and is valid; and (2) after readyState is 4.

Comment: Hmm... I haven't got Hulu account. Can you make some JSFiddle or something?

Comment: The provided code works properly on youtube. Perhaps it's an issue specific to Hulu.

Comment: Yes, it works fine on Youtube and many other players. Hulu is doing something to block or cancel the call to currentTime.

Comment: Small warning: the readyState 4 tells that it's loaded enough to be watched, not that it's been fully loaded.

Comment: Same for W3C Video example. You can use those controllers. I believe this might be Hulu-related, but I do not have an account either. +1 to the JSFiddle (or equivalent) example.

Comment: Guys: I am happy to do a jsfiddle, but this being Hulu-specific, how would that even work? Hulu has to be running to replicate the problem and experiment with fixes. I will set up a 30-day Hulu account for anyone that thinks they can solve this.

Comment: Are you seeking to a timestamp that would've otherwise required you to watch an ad? I am able to set the video's `currentTime` so long as the value I set it to would not require me to play another ad.

Comment: idbehold, you are right! As long as I skip/seek within the bounds of allowable video and not try to cut into a commercial it works. I feel dumb. Thanks for taking the time to look into this. Can you post your answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, it will first pause then set your position then again play

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].pause();
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].currentTime = 500;
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1].play();
```

Comment: As mentioned in origional post, direct calls to currentTime break the player. I had already tried what you're suggesting and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this code.

```
function setTime(tValue) {
        //  if no video is loaded, this throws an exception 
            try {
                if (tValue == 0) {
                    video.currentTime = tValue;
                }
                else {
                    video.currentTime += tValue;
                }

             } catch (err) {
                 // errMessage(err) // show exception
             errMessage("Video content might not be loaded");
               }
     }
```

Comment: The video is always loaded, that's not the problem.

Comment: As per the question details there is no error while setting `currentTime`

Comment: Can you try it in try and catch? Log error, because I tried forwarding video and it works perfectly for me. So if it's freezing in your case there must be some error. Even on Hulu also it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVideo=document.getElementsByTagName("video")
if(myVideo[1] != undefind)
{
    myVideo[1].currentTime=500;
}
/* or provide id to each video tag and use getElementById('id')    */
var myVideo=document.getElementById("videoId")
if(myVideo != undefind)
{
    myVideo.currentTime=500;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the video is always loaded (never undefined, after the page is finished loading). Also, you spelled `undefined` wrong, so your code will break.

Comment: As per the question details there is no error while setting `currentTime`

Answer (score 0):

Pls. try this:

```
hv = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[1];

hv.play();
hv.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    this.currentTime = 500;
});
```