# Chrome extension popup closes unexpectedly then becomes unclickable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Chrome extension I built that I've been testing. It runs fine on PC and never crashes. But on MAC, occasionally/randomly the popup window suddenly closes, presumably because some kind of unhandled exception occurred. I didn't click outside the popup or do anything that would naturally cause it to close. But I was doing things inside the popup window that calls functions, so I believe that some kind of error is occurring, but it only happens on Mac.

What is even worse, as soon as the extension popup closes, it cannot be opened again. Clicking on the extension icon (which normally causes the popup to appear as a small window just beneath the icon) does nothing. Click, click, click...nothing.

The problem is, the associated Chrome developer console window linked to the extension popup also closes whenever the popup closes, so I can't think of any way to discover the error that is happening.

Is there some way I can discover what is causing my extension popup to unexpectedly close? And/or any way to discover why it won't show the popup again after it closes unexpectedly?

Note: I'm all about showing source code, but in this case it would seem unhelpful because I don't know which code to show. My extension popup has thousands of lines of javascript, and it all works fine on a windows PC.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. try [enabling logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging), or 2. open the background page devtools, go to Performance/Timeline, start recording, then crash the popup, stop recording and inspect the flame-chart (the extension's pages share the same process)

Comment: wOxxOm thanks for weighing in. This is great advice and I am pursuing it. Could you also please take a look at my SO post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635136/html5-video-setting-video-currenttime-breaks-the-player    THANK YOU.